# How to fix ClientMissingIntents with discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I don't understand. What's wrong? All rights to the developer portal have been granted.
I still don't understand, even if I don't remove it all, the error remains. My current `javascript` code:

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

dotenv.config();

// handlers register
const updateStatus = require("./src/utils/richPresence");

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);`
```

```
> Node.js v20.11.1
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\nikita folder\WukkiDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:492
> throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.ClientMissingIntents);
>       ^
> 
> TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
> at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\nikita folder\WukkiDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:492:13)
> at new Client (C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\nikita folder\WukkiDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\nikita folder\WukkiDiscordBot\src\utils\richPresence.js:3:16)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alena\Desktop\nikita folder\WukkiDiscordBot\index.js:8:22) {
> code: 'ClientMissingIntents'
> }
> 
> Node.js v20.11.1
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

elementary I want to run a bot with custom rich presence, but it does not want to work at startup

Comment: What does contain your file `./src/utils/richPresence`?